# Hi guys, im new to django i want to display the value of ChoiceField

Tags: django, choicefield

there is no error but there's no value/display of category in the template

**forms.py :**

```
class UploadwContentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    TYPE_OF_FILE_CHOICES = (
             ('CATEGORY 1','CATEGORY 1'),
             ('CATEGORY 1','Catergoty 2'),
            ('CATEGORY 1','Catergoty 3'),
            ('CATEGORY 1','Catergoty 4')
           )

    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
         'class': 'form-control',
         'placeholder' : 'Enter your title here:'
         }
       ) )

    category = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={
         'class' : 'btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle'
     }), choices=TYPE_OF_FILE_CHOICES)
```

**views.py:**

```
def uploadlist(request):
     uploadwcontent = UploadwContent.objects.all()
     return render(request, 'upload/uploadlist.html', {
                            'uploadwcontent' : uploadwcontent
                             })
```

**template_views.py**

```
  {% for uploadwcontent  in uploadwcontent%}
     <td> {{uploadwcontent.title}}</td>
     <td>{{ uploadwcontent.author}}</td>
     <td>
         <a href="{{ uploadwcontent.pdf.url}}" class="btn-primary btn-sm "target="_blank">
             Download PDF 
         </a>
     </td>
     <td>
         {{form.get_category_display}}
     </td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the view to use

`render(request, 'upload/uploadlist.html', { 'uploadwcontents' : uploadwcontent })`

and alter the for loop in the template to be

`{% for uploadwcontent  in uploadwcontents %}`

Your for loop needs to be of the style `for someitem in collection_of_items`